# How to share persistent queue "Inter-app" in Mulesoft?

Tags: queue, message-queue, connector, mulesoft

We are trying to perform the simplest publish / consume action among two different applications in the public VPC.

The publisher APP is working as expected. It generates the queue and publishes all the messages correctly.

[image]
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <vm:config name="VM_Config" doc:name="VM Config" doc:id="1c2283b1-26a8-4fc9-b048-b50bbee08e62" >
        <vm:queues >
            <vm:queue queueName="order" queueType="PERSISTENT" />
        </vm:queues>
    </vm:config>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="6f88c504-19e6-4cca-8b50-efb95b2dcbc8" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="sltestpqpubFlow" doc:id="23315e3e-49b0-4f61-a86c-321a2cb9c4ad" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="2268dae5-2e89-45f4-a685-50602bea4205" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/fire"/>
        <vm:publish queueName="order" doc:name="Publish" doc:id="e928d591-4f4a-4d54-9390-3e69dd2520b8" config-ref="VM_Config">
            <vm:content ><![CDATA[#["Message sent"]]]></vm:content>
        </vm:publish>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="2eba63dd-15d0-4961-9c75-de8fee366caa" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

The listener APP on the other hand is creating its own persistent queue with the same name. Therefore, not consuming the messages published by the app mentioned above.

[image]

```
<mule xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd">

    <vm:config name="VM_Config" doc:name="VM Config" doc:id="c9d8390d-cc35-4188-b034-70cb144f2da7">
        <vm:connection >
            <reconnection failsDeployment="true" >
                <reconnect />
            </reconnection>
        </vm:connection>
        <vm:queues >
            <vm:queue queueName="order" queueType="PERSISTENT" />
        </vm:queues>
    </vm:config>
    <flow name="sltestpqFlow" doc:id="1681828e-0889-4c2f-8f03-cebe7cf852cd" >
        <vm:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="4b1a3db0-946d-4428-a7b8-b2e3aebd88fa" config-ref="VM_Config" queueName="order" transactionalAction="ALWAYS_BEGIN" transactionType="XA">
            <reconnect />
        </vm:listener>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="8efdd42a-9f73-4e07-80bd-b42cafed297f" message="Got event"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Not sure what we are missing for a single queue sharing (instead of each application having it's own)

UPDATE 02/20/2020 11:10 AM PST

We are using the VM Connector v2.0 in Mule 4
https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/vm/vm-reference

Comment: I guess that you are using some queue connector. You need to provide more details, like what connector, version of the connector, what is the broker, if using JMS, or some more details. For example for JMS, if it is a persistent queue, or a topic. 
Screenshots of flows are useless to communicate details of the configuration. It is much more useful to show the equivalent XML configuration.

Comment: Thank you @aled !! I am very new to Mulesoft development, sorry for not providing enough info. I added the connector used, the version and the xml behind the flow components. We are not using a JMS broker at this point or any other broker for this matter, we are just trying to share a persistent queue among 2 apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VM connector only works inside the same JVM. In the case of applications deployed in CloudHub, it means inside the same application only. You can not share messages with any other applications. You need to bring your own JMS broker, installed somewhere where the applications can access it, some other message service with a connector for Mule 4, or use Anypoint MQ.

Comment: In the documentation link I posted the first sentence contradicts what you are stating. It clearly says it handles inter-app communication through asynchronous queues. This doesn't make sense. Can you help me understand why they claim that if the connector is confined to the same JVM?

Comment: There is no contradiction. The documentation is correct, but it refers to on prem installations of Mule where several applications can be deployed in the same Mule instance, which also implies in the same JVM. When an application is deployed to CloudHub it is deployed in its own Mule instance, that is not shared with any other application, hence the VM connector can not connect with other applications deployed in CloudHub, which are in their own separate Mule instances each.

Comment: Thank you @aled for confirming what it sounded like in your first response. Making sure I understood correctly. This will help us model different approaches mainly with a JMS broker vs Anypoint MQ. Have a great weekend sir.